# Add scrolling to Lightbox2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox2

[Heres an image of the issue I'm trying to resolve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qcRG.jpg) I am working on my portfolio site; and I have images of some of my personal projects, all of them are the same width but some have different heights. Due to getting full page screenshots of my work, some of the images have a much greater height than others. Instead of allowing displaying all the images the same size and allowing scrolling in the modal window, it scales the images down to fit within the same height as all the others. This gives it an odd look cause some of the images get scaled down a lot. I would like to get all the images to display in the same width, and those that need it to allow scrolling to see the rest of the image. I tried to use overflow: scroll; on the .lightbox but that didn't help. I've also tried overflow-y. I would also like to disable the page in the background from being able to scroll, to allow the scrolling to be focused on the images that it is necessary on.

```css
.lightbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
    
}

.lightbox .lb-image {
  display: block;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 3px;  
  /* Image border */
  border: 4px solid white;
}

.lightbox a img {
  border: none;
}

.lb-outerContainer {
  position: relative;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* Background color behind image.
     This is visible during transitions. */
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: All of my images are 2880px wide, but they range from 1562-11014px. The image with a very large height get scaled down a lot.

Comment: a working example would make it a lot easier for us to give you a proper answer. try adding a code snippet to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Lightbox2 by default appends calculated width & height to the image and `.lb-outerContainer`. But you can override this by doing the following -

```
.lb-outerContainer {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
.lightbox .lb-image {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

**I don't recommend this** because this breaks the intended use of this plugin. I'm sure you'll find an alternative to lightbox2 that achieves what you're looking for. So you can consider this as a temporary fix.

**EDIT:** Here's a jsfiddle to see it work. https://jsfiddle.net/hsugx6wm/43/

Comment: I want to keep the lightbox window the same size, just have the images that have overflow be able to scroll down within that window.

Comment: @AaronKell i've added a jsfiddle that has additional override CSS to make it close to what you're describing.